# Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: fp in Backend

Tags: magento2.4.5, facebook-pixel

We are using [Facebook Meta Extension in github](https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-for-magento2)  , We are getting below error in the Backend Configuration

[image]

Here is LogOrganisation.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright (c) Meta Platforms, Inc. and affiliates. All Rights Reserved
 */

 /**
 * Helper class for generating and organizing log files.
 */
namespace Facebook\BusinessExtension\Helper;
// protected $fp;

class LogOrganization
{
    // 4096 -- Good balance for tracking backwards
    const BUFFER = 4096;

    static $criticalLines = array();

    public static function organizeLogs() {
        $arrayOfFiles = array("var/log/debug.log", "var/log/cron.log", "var/log/magento.cron.log", "var/log/system.log");
        $countCrit = 0;

        foreach($arrayOfFiles as $value) {
            if (!file_exists($value)) {
                continue;
            }

         $fp = fopen($value, 'r');
            $pos = -2; // Skip final new line character (Set to -1 if not present)
            $currentLine = '';

            while (-1 !== fseek($fp, $pos, SEEK_END)) {
                $char = fgetc($fp);
                if ("\n" == $char) {
                    if (substr($currentLine, 0, 3) == "[20") {
                        $time = strtotime(substr($currentLine, 1, 20));
                        if ($time > strtotime('-7 day')) {
                            break;
                        }

                        // Saving only critical log entries with "Facebook" phrase
                        if (strpos($currentLine, "CRITICAL") !== false &&
                            strpos($currentLine, "Facebook") !== false) {
                            self::$criticalLines[] = $currentLine;
                            $countCrit++;
                        }
                        $currentLine = '';

                        if ($countCrit == 500) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $currentLine = $char . $currentLine;
                }
                $pos--;
            }

            if (substr($currentLine, 0, 3) == "[20") {
                $time = strtotime(substr($currentLine, 1, 20));
                if ($time > strtotime('-7 day')) {
                    break;
                }

                if (strpos($currentLine, "CRITICAL") !== false  &&
                    strpos($currentLine, "Facebook") !== false) {
                    self::$criticalLines[] = $currentLine;
                    $countCrit++;
                }
                $currentLine = '';
            }

            $countCrit = 0;
        }
        fclose($fp);

        $amuLogs = self::tailCustom("var/log/facebook-business-extension.log", 100);
        $amuLogsArr = explode("\n", $amuLogs);
        self::$criticalLines = array_merge(self::$criticalLines, $amuLogsArr);

        usort(self::$criticalLines, function ($x, $y) {
            $t1 = strtotime(substr($x, 1, 19));
            $t2 = strtotime(substr($y, 1, 19));

            return ($t1 - $t2);
        });

        return self::$criticalLines;
    }

    public static function tailCustom($filepath, $lines) {
        $f = fopen($filepath, "rb");
        if ($f === false) {
            return false;
        }

        fseek($f, -1, SEEK_END);
        if (fread($f, 1) != "\n") {
            $lines -= 1;
        }

        $output = '';
        $chunk = '';

        while (ftell($f) > 0 && $lines >=   0) {
            $seek = min(ftell($f), self::BUFFER);
            fseek($f, -$seek, SEEK_CUR);
            $output = ($chunk = fread($f, $seek)) . $output;
            fseek($f, -mb_strlen($chunk, '8bit'), SEEK_CUR);
            $lines -= substr_count($chunk, "\n");
        }

        while ($lines++ < 0) {
            $output = substr($output, strpos($output, "\n") + 1);
        }

        fclose($f);
        return trim($output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to declare variable with null, like $fp = ""; at beginning of the function

Comment: @AzizKapasi here i got : `Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in`

Comment: @AzizKapasi here : https://pastebin.com/ZxbqM6WY  i updated as you suggested

Comment: Oh I'm sorry function accepts array, so you have to declare blank array. look in yout foreach loop you are not getting any of the array value of $arrayOfFiles.. just first try to add log to this file so you can understand where and what is the issue is

Comment: @AzizKapasi Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You encountered this error because the variable `$fp` is declared inside the `foreach` loop, but you are trying to access it outside of the loop.

To resolve this issue, move the code `fclose($fp);` from line **75** to the end of the `foreach` loop.
Your code should look like this:

```
foreach($arrayOfFiles as $value) {
    if (!file_exists($value)) {
        continue;
    }

    $fp = fopen($value, 'r');
    //...other code

    $countCrit = 0;
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: @Baby in Magento, try this

Comment: 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: fopen(var/log/facebook-business-extension.log): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/glow-staging/vendor/facebook/facebook-for-magento2/Helper/LogOrganization.php on line 92

Comment: here is full code : https://pastebin.com/3s71mWRu  and error  :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXoA3.png

Comment: have you checked in var/log/ directory if facebook-business-extension.log file is available or not?

Comment: @AzizKapasi starange that no log errors related to this in log directory

Comment: @BabyinMagento create a new one with that file name to resolve the issue.

Comment: @TuVan you are telling me to create new file with same name, i will try now

Comment: @TuVan  updated error :   https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYlFz.png

Comment: I mean create the **facebook-business-extension.log** file within the `var/log` directory. Can you confirm?

Comment: @TuVan sorry, here is updated code : https://pastebin.com/FxcibJbx ,  updated error :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZaJj.png , also no error displaying in log file, i created new log file as you suggested.

Comment: The version of the module in the facebookarchive GitHub repository is deprecated and archived. It is recommended to uninstall this module and instead install the new module from Magento Marketplace at https://commercemarketplace.adobe.com/meta-meta-for-magento2.html. However, if you prefer to install the latest version of their module, you can consider installing it from GitHub at https://github.com/magento/meta-for-magento2/